# elasticsearch-query receiving 0 records for a query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm receiving 0 records for the following query:

```json
{ 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "appInfo.additionalInfo.DeviceID": "84A29458-C63F-4875-AFD0-0BD9E19559B3"       
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the following query returns 0 records:

```json
{ 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "appInfo.additionalInfo.DeviceID.keyword": "84A29458-C63F-4875-AFD0-0BD9E19559B3"       
    }
  }
}
```

The data is:

```json
{
  "userInfo": {
    "additionalInfo": {
      "DeviceID": "84A29458-C63F-4875-AFD0-0BD9E19559B3"
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping is:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "userInfo": {
      "properties": {
        "additionalInfo": {
          "properties": {
            "DeviceID": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query against `userInfo.additionalInfo.DeviceID` field. Modify your search query as

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "userInfo.additionalInfo.DeviceID.keyword": "84A29458-C63F-4875-AFD0-0BD9E19559B3"       
    }
  }
}
```